# Smart card programming with MPCOS EMV r5

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I would like to create a little bonus-point project with MPCOS smart cards, especially with this one: [http://www.procard.pl/img/site/29/MPCOS_EMV_R5.pdf](http://MPCOS%20EMV%20r5%20smartcard)

I'm a senior software developer and with my current understanding I have to:

- create the directory structure for this card (is this customizable? or is it a standard?)
- creating APDU command set (on the card? or on the POS terminal?)
- creating algorythm for secure information (ie. name) and points
- creating graphics layout - but this is not dev-related:)

So I would like to see how "static" this smart card world is and how I the basic steps (or the first steps) to do have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might improve your question to get (more/better) answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have the appropriate card Reference Manual? Without it you _probably_ won't get any further. AFAIK this card is pretty customizable, supports secure messaging+secret codes (i.e. it is resistant to cloning) and electronic purse (for the bonus/loyalty points). The security algorithms are fixed and described in the reference manual (together with supported APDU commands),

Comment: thank you vip. I don't have the manual but a good starting would be great. ie.: whare can I define APDU command collections? How should I "upload" them etc.

Answer (score 2):

The card in question is a native card (as opposed to Javacard) and therefore brings its ready-made set of APDUs as well as algorithms. Your application will still have build the corresponding commands (and they are likely not to work with the card of another manufacturer) and decode the responses.

Since the card is flagged multi-application, you should be able to create your own (card) application DF containing everything required.

Comment: just a question: what is DF?

Comment: DFs(dedicated file)  are the directories of the smart card filing system, and EFs (elementary file) the ordinary files. An application DF is a kind of top-level directoy directly under the MF (master file, corresponding to root directory in Unix).